# NullPointerException - sending email in Java (using Spring library)

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I can't send email in my web application, something is wrong with 
`MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();` line, here is a code:

MailSender:

```
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;  

public void send(String from, String to, String subject, String body)  throws MessagingException {

    MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper;

    helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true); 

    helper.setFrom(from);
    helper.setSubject(subject);
    helper.setTo(to);
    helper.setText(body, true); 


    javaMailSender.send(message);   
}
```

Error:

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-dispatcher] in context with path [/OnlineShop] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.damian.model.MailSender.send(MailSender.java:19)
```

Comment: Has `javaMailSender` been initialized before invoking the method?

Comment: The `JavaMailSender` should be a spring configured and injected bean. If that is the case then make sure you aren't creating new instances of the class you posted here.